# Creating each row for each item for a user in spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark data frame like below:

```
  User  Item    Purchased
1   A   1
1   B   2
2   A   3
2   C   4
3   A   3
3   B   2
3   D   6

only showing top 5 rows
```

each user has a row for an item they have purchased. Assume Purhcased to be how many qty. purchased (count).

However there are items which a user might not have purchased so for that item that particular user doesn't have a row. We only have rows for items which a user has purchased. So if user 1 has purchased item A, B, we have 2 rows for user 1 corresponding to these two items. But if user 2 has purchased A, C then user 2 has rows for item A and C but no B. I want in the end each user should have all rows for all items in the table with the corresponding count of each.

I want to convert this data frame into a data frame as above but also having rows for items which a user has not seen and give the corresponding count as zero.

Like below:

```
User    Item    Purchased
1   A   1
1   B   2
1   C   0
1   D   0
2   A   3
2   C   4
2   B   0
2   D   0
3   A   3
3   B   2
3   D   6
3   C   0
only showing top 5 rows
```

One way I thought was that in spark if I use cross_tab method of sqlContext on the first data frame then I can convert each row to column with corresponding values. For item which user doesn't have it will create a column for the same and put zero there.

But then how to convert back those columns to rows?. It might also be a roundabout way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1, 'A', 2), (1, 'B', 3), (2, 'A', 2)], ['user', 'item', 'purchased'])
pivot = df.groupBy('user').pivot('item').sum('purchased').fillna(0)
items = [i['item'] for i in df.select('item').distinct().collect()]
flattened_rdd = pivot.rdd.flatMap(lambda x: [(x['user'], i, x[i]) for i in items])
sqlContext.createDataFrame(flattened_rdd, ["user", "item", "purchased"]).show()
```

Comment: What is purchase_count variable here? Also why take average there? I want the actual count as it is there in the data

Comment: Ok this code is taking ages to run. I am running it on my laptop spark but its too time consuming

Comment: @Baktaawar i named purchased as purchase_count. Edited my code to reflect that. Not sure why it took so long.  I ran it on my laptop with 1249956 rows it ran in 4 secs. Here is the code for creating sample input. `output = []
alphabets = list(string.uppercase)
for i in range(1,100000):
    mod = i % len(alphabets)
    for j in range(0, mod):
        output.append((i, alphabets[j], 1))`

Comment: Well I don't know. You code kept running for 12 hours and didn't finish. So I had to use the below code by @avr. It ran in 45 mins. I have 56K users with 8.5K distinct items in the table. My item name is not single character. It is long strings.

Comment: Doing `collect()` on big dataset is not recommended and it should be used for small datasets and for debugging purposes.

Comment: @avr I agree. But in this case i'm using collect on the distinct items.

Comment: @None what if distinct data is big?

Comment: distinct items are 8.5k

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this by just using only `df` functions as well.

```
orders = [(1,"A",1),(1,"B",2),(2,"A",3),(2,"C",4),(3,"A",3),(3,"B",2),(3,"D",6)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(orders, ["user","item","purchased"])
df_items = df.select("item").distinct().repartition(5).withColumnRenamed("item", "item_1")
df_users = df.select("user").distinct().repartition(5).withColumnRenamed("user", "user_1")
df_cartesian = df_users.join(df_items)
//above expression returns cartesian product of users and items dfs
joined_df = df_cartesian.join(df, [df_cartesian.user_1==df.user, df_cartesian.item_1==df.item], "left_outer").drop("user").drop("item")
result_df = joined_df.fillna(0,["purchased"]).withColumnRenamed("item_1", "item").withColumnRenamed("user_1", "user")
```

Finally, `result_df.show()` produces desire output shown below:

```
+----+----+---------+
|user|item|purchased|
+----+----+---------+
|   2|   A|        3|
|   2|   B|        0|
|   2|   C|        4|
|   2|   D|        0|
|   3|   A|        3|
|   3|   B|        2|
|   3|   C|        0|
|   3|   D|        6|
|   1|   A|        1|
|   1|   B|        2|
|   1|   C|        0|
|   1|   D|        0|
+----+----+---------+
```

Comment: Do I need repartitions?

Comment: Yes, otherwise `df_users.join(df_items)` creates `200*200` tasks. where 200 is default number of partitions.

Comment: the problem is it is not running. Taking more than 12 hours to run and even then no result. I have like 300K obs.

Comment: Did you repartition `users` and `items` table? How many rows(distinct) do you have in each `users` and `items` table?  What is input data size?

Comment: I did repartition as indicated. My data frame is 300K rows. There are 56K distinct users and 8.5K distinct items. However 56x8.5K doesn't equal 300k because we only have user-item rows for which user has purchased. If a user has not purchased an item it's not there. Just like the above first table.

Comment: It's quite difficult to handle with single machine especially while calculating `joined_df` because it will join 56*8.5 K dataset with 300K dataset which is really trivial to run on single machine in my opinion! Did you try debugging through line by line ?

Comment: Well it ran. But took more than half an hour. :-|. You think something can be done to speed this up?. Also I was trying to save this as an parquet file. That is even taking longer.

Comment: I don't whether we can speed up this by using some other optimizations (bcz catalyst will take care of that). Consider giving decent cpu's.

Comment: The problem is earlier when I just had 300K rows it was not a lot of time to train an algo on that data. But now with this size of data it is like very long to even train that. And any data manipulation I do now is again taking time to do that.

Comment: Consider using `cache`, if you are running multiple operations on resultant dataframe.

Comment: thanks. What if I have an RDD of the same value (RDD of tuples). Can I use the same code?. I guess the part where you are creating df_items and df_users won't work since that uses df.select etc

Comment: Don't go to RDD when you have Dataframe.  As you know df operations are much optimized than RDD.

Comment: This worked well for me, and I did not have marked speed issues working with 5K users and 6K items.